# JPA container addressbook missing artifact

Tags: java, maven, vaadin, addressbook

So I tried to load a zipped version of the JPA addressbook using Maven as is instructed in the tutorial, but I have this error, where it says there's a missing artifact.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin.addon</groupId>
        <artifactId>jpacontainer</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

It says this artifact is missing japcontainer.jar:2.1.1, and when I change version to these numbers, I still get the same error. I'm a little lost, and don't really understand what I'm doing. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Here's the tutorial:
https://vaadin.com/download/jpacontainer-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Go to http://vaadin.com/directory and search "jpacontainer". Then you can see on the right the dependency snippet with latest version and the repository snippet as well. For jpacontainer the dependency is:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.vaadin.addon</groupId>
  <artifactId>jpacontainer</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The artifact id used to be bit different a while ago when it was still dual licensed.

Slightly unrelated to this, if you are figuring out how to connect JPA backend to Vaadin UI, I suggest not to use jpacontainer, even though I have been developing its major renewal a while ago. It is handy for some cases, but has some architectural annoyances. Instead I'd suggest to check out [this example project](https://github.com/mstahv/jpa-addressbook) and use it as a basis.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the **pom.xml** file and add he following lines to the `<repositories>` section:

```
<repository>
  <id>vaadin-addons</id>
  <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
</repository>
```

That's because the vaadin addons are not located on the main maven repository-

Comment: I think these lines are already included in the repository section.

Comment: In this case the artifactId is wrong.  Maybe it should be jpacontainer-addon? Check again the documentation